# Linux Mint Postfix connection refused

Tags: email, linux-mint, postfix

I'm trying to create a server on Linux Mint (Cinnamon 19.2) for HTTP (Apache2, Mysql5.7, PHP7.2), FTP, and Email (Postfix, and evetually Dovecot and SquirrelMail or RoundCube, but after I get Postfix running) - the server/domain is nutima-laera.go.ro. HTTP and FTP work just fine, however I have been stuck on Postfix for the last couple of days.
I keep getting:

```
Oct 24 15:37:35 nutima-laera postfix/qmgr[11832]: BAFBC2034FD: from=<root@nutima-laera.go.ro>, size=357, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 24 15:37:37 nutima-laera postfix/smtp[13039]: connect to relay1.go.ro[81.196.20.132]:25: Connection refused
Oct 24 15:37:39 nutima-laera postfix/smtp[13039]: connect to relay2.go.ro[81.196.20.132]:25: Connection refused
Oct 24 15:37:39 nutima-laera postfix/smtp[13039]: BAFBC2034FD: to=<speedy_rudolf@yahoo.com>, relay=none, delay=2001, delays=1997/0.01/4.1/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to relay2.go.ro[81.196.20.132]:25: Connection refused)
```

Port 25 is not blocked by either firewall (added excetion just to be sure) or isp, I can telnet localhost 25, google.com 25, nutima-laera.go.ro 25 locally and externally. Telnet connects just fine to all of these.

Main.cf:

```
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

compatibility_level = 2

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = nutima-laera.go.ro
#myhostname = mail.nutima-laera.go.ro
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain, localhost, mail.nutima-laera.go.ro, nutima-laera.go.ro
relayhost = $mydomain
#mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks = 192.168.100.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_protocols = all
mynetworks_style = subnet
#myorigin = $mydomain
myorigin = nutima-laera.go.ro
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
```

master.cf:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
    -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

The comments left are to show some of what i have tried.
I should mention that I did use Webmin for install and initial setup, but after that failed, I started using the terminal.
If there is any other information that you need, I will post it.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use an external STMP host to send your emails you have to set the host,username and password in /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd:

```
[mail.host.com] username:password
```

Then you need to insert this line in main.cf:

```
 relayhost = [mail.host.com]:25
```

Also have you checked with your ISP that they are not blocking port 25 as some do, and you have to go around this by using port 2525

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. Like i said in my post, port 25 is not blocked. Telnet to port 25 connects ok. And no, I would like to make my server the SMTP host, not use an external one. Thank you.

Comment: you main conf is not complete, can you post it in full so maybe I or some one can help you. Also mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain, localhost is enough no need for the extra domains

Comment: try sending your self an email from the terminal : echo "test message" | mail -s "This is a Subject" -a "From: you@example.com" you@example.com"

Comment: here is a slandered Conf for postfix http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html

Comment: Here is output of mailing myself:<br>
      Oct 25 06:33:44 nutima-laera postfix/error[1635]: 48E1C2034B4: to=<speedy.rudolf.server@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=60891, delays=60885/5.6/0/0.38, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to relay2.go.ro[81.196.20.132]:25: Connection refused)<br>
      Oct 25 06:33:44 nutima-laera postfix/error[1625]: 45BB72034FE: to=<speedy_rudolf@yahoo.com>, relay=none, delay=54799, delays=54793/5.5/0/0.36, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to relay2.go.ro[81.196.20.132]:25: Connection refused)<br>

Comment: @RomanClaudiu is this your server:  relay1.go.ro[81.196.20.132]:25: or you are sending mail through it?

Comment: Oct 25 06:38:39 nutima-laera postfix/pickup[1245]: 0DE3D203152: uid=0 from=<root@nutima-laera.go.ro>
      Oct 25 06:38:39 nutima-laera postfix/cleanup[2968]: 0DE3D203152: message-id=<20191025033839.0DE3D203152@nutima-laera.go.ro>
      Oct 25 06:38:39 nutima-laera postfix/qmgr[1246]: 0DE3D203152: from=<root@nutima-laera.go.ro>, size=350, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
      Oct 25 06:38:39 nutima-laera postfix/local[2970]: 0DE3D203152: to=<root@nutima-laera.go.ro>, relay=local, delay=0.18, delays=0.09/0.08/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)

Comment: That is the yahoo or gmail server, and i'm send mail to it, not through it.

Comment: @RomanClaudiu make a telnet 81.196.20.132 25 and check dose it connect

Comment: try sending to a different email I just tried it : telnet 81.196.20.132 25  : Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: I got connection refused to telnet 81.196.20.132 25

Comment: I just realized, there might be a relay problem. Both yahoo and gmail go through the same relay that refuses the connection. I will have a talk with my isp, see what's going on. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RomanClaudiu Your welcome